# Copying the Angular library's asset files to the project assets folders

Tags: angular, copy, assets

I have a library that I have developed on angular. There are some asset files (images, styles, fonts, scripts) in this library.

What I want to do is; If this library is installed via npm, the asset files of the library will be automatically get copied to the project's "assets" folder.

I hope I was able to explain. Is such a thing possible, what is the best way to do it?

Comment: I believe you will have to include these assets in the angular.json -> assets section

Comment: I did this but it doesn't copy. As soon as I install the library (exam: npm install @library.v.1.0), I want it to automatically copy from the node_modules folder to the assets folder of my project.

Comment: I see. my proposal would assure library assets would get to build result when you call ng build. in your case small postbuild script with copy functionality could be usefull

Comment: I have no experience in writing post build scripts. Is it possible for you to assist?